# position: sticky and borders

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a scrollable list with "sticky" headers. So far the functionality seems to be working, however there are some visual issues.

The list itself is based on a `ul` marked with the `Bootstrap 5` class `list-group`. As a starting point, it looks like this

[image: starting-point]

When I start scrolling, the two levels of headers "stick" as expected

[image: scroll-start]

[image: scroll-continue]

As you can see from the screenshots, the border between the "stuck" headers disappears. It is my understanding that it is part of the browser default behaviour, and it doesn't really bother me. However if I continue to scroll so that the second `First Level` header sticks, the behaviour is not consistent anymore. The top border has disappeared, and instead we have a border separating the two "stuck" headers.

[image: scroll-issue]

If I continue scrolling the issue remains

[image: scroll-issue-continues]

Full source code:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2r5pn4g/)

I am not sure if this is "expected" behaviour or if I can somehow fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here turns out to be that only the first `.list-group-item` has a top border.

You can solve this by adding `.border-top` to each of your `.sticky-*` elements.

```html
<li class="list-group-item sticky-top sticky-first border-top">...</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/krxfsgp9/

---

### Or...

If you are using SASS, you can just extend `.border-top` and `.sticky-top` in your custom class rules.

```css
        .sticky-first, 
        .sticky-second {
            @extend .sticky-top;
            @extend .border-top;
            top: 0;
        }

        .sticky-second {
            top: 41px;
        }
```

Then use like this:

```html
<li class="list-group-item sticky-first">...</li>
<li class="list-group-item sticky-second">...</li>
```